# Click Listener for 2 images from a Listview

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview and it has 2 images in each item.
How can i get the click listener for the images.

If image 1 is clicked then i need to go to page1 
If image 2 is clicked then i need to go to page2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set onClickListener on each imageView in each listItem's viewHolder:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate("YOUR_LAYOUT_RESOURCE", parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.imageView1 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        viewHolder.imageView2 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.imageView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // things to do onClicked
            }
        });

    viewHolder.imageView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // things to do onClicked
            }
        });


    return convertView;
}

class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imageView1;
    public ImageView imageView2;
}
```

Comment: any way to get the position at the image ClickListener. My current listview clicklistener.   listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
      long arg3) {
     itemcategorylist=arrayOfcategorylist.get(position);
     Constant.CATEGORYLIST_CIDD=itemcategorylist.getCategoryId();
     Log.e("itemcategorylist", ""+Constant.CATEGORYLIST_CIDD);
     Intent intentalbert=new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),Category_images.class);
     startActivity(intentalbert);
    }
   });

Comment: you could just access the position parameter inside each OnClickListener instances